# Webpack how to compile all js files in folder and move them to other one

Tags: javascript, webpack, laravel-mix

I need a way to compile all my js files in resources/js folder and move them to another folder. I use laravel-mix, but I can extend it with webpack. Need either laravel-mix solution or webpack solution

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this webpack plugin: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin